# Pivot data and maintain original sort order

Tags: python, pandas, google-visualization

I'd like to pivot my data which results from a django queryset while maintaining the original (non-alphabetical) sort order on the index column. The pivoted data will then be used in a google visualization line chart.

I've hacked together my own code to do the job but it's a bit ugly and I was wondering if it could be done using a pandas DataFrame pivot.

I've never used pandas before so, after reading the doco, this is what I came up with.

Here is my unpivoted data frame, sorted by date and tenor where tenor suffixes represent: D=Day, M=Month, Y=Year.

```
df = DataFrame(data)

               date tenor     value
0        2014-01-01    1D  0.517125
1        2014-01-01    1M    0.5175
2        2014-01-01    2M  0.518159
3        2014-01-01    3M    0.5187
4        2014-01-01    4M   0.51912
5        2014-01-01    5M   0.51949
6        2014-01-01    6M    0.5197
7        2014-01-01    9M  0.519511
8        2014-01-01    1Y    0.5198
9        2014-01-01   18M  0.521228
10       2014-01-01    2Y  0.523097
11       2014-01-01    3Y  0.525054
12       2014-01-01    4Y  0.527055
13       2014-01-01    5Y  0.529054
14       2014-01-01    6Y  0.531099
15       2014-01-01    7Y  0.532852
16       2014-01-01    8Y  0.534207
17       2014-01-01    9Y  0.535314
18       2014-01-02    1D  0.517874
19       2014-01-02    1M    0.5181
20       2014-01-02    2M  0.518451
21       2014-01-02    3M    0.5188
22       2014-01-02    4M  0.519113
23       2014-01-02    5M  0.519418
24       2014-01-02    6M    0.5196
25       2014-01-02    9M  0.519377
26       2014-01-02    1Y    0.5197
27       2014-01-02   18M  0.521406
28       2014-01-02    2Y  0.523405
29       2014-01-02    3Y  0.525254
30       2014-01-02    4Y  0.527151
31       2014-01-02    5Y  0.529256
32       2014-01-02    6Y  0.531543
33       2014-01-02    7Y  0.533457
34       2014-01-02    8Y  0.534802
35       2014-01-02    9Y  0.535847
36       2014-01-03    1D  0.518552
37       2014-01-03    1M    0.5186
38       2014-01-03    2M  0.518536
39       2014-01-03    3M    0.5186
40       2014-01-03    4M  0.518865
41       2014-01-03    5M   0.51916
42       2014-01-03    6M    0.5193
43       2014-01-03    9M  0.519024
44       2014-01-03    1Y    0.5193
45       2014-01-03   18M  0.520882
46       2014-01-03    2Y    0.5228
47       2014-01-03    3Y  0.524647
48       2014-01-03    4Y  0.526752
49       2014-01-03    5Y  0.528957
50       2014-01-03    6Y  0.531065
51       2014-01-03    7Y  0.532856
52       2014-01-03    8Y  0.534325
53       2014-01-03    9Y  0.535558
```

Using pandas pivot produces the following results. The pivot worked but the rows are in the wrong order.

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='tenor', columns='date', values='value')
tenor            2014-01-01 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
18M                0.521228   0.521406   0.520882
1D                 0.517125   0.517874   0.518552
1M                   0.5175     0.5181     0.5186
1Y                   0.5198     0.5197     0.5193
2M                 0.518159   0.518451   0.518536
2Y                 0.523097   0.523405     0.5228
3M                   0.5187     0.5188     0.5186
3Y                 0.525054   0.525254   0.524647
4M                  0.51912   0.519113   0.518865
4Y                 0.527055   0.527151   0.526752
5M                  0.51949   0.519418    0.51916
5Y                 0.529054   0.529256   0.528957
6M                   0.5197     0.5196     0.5193
6Y                 0.531099   0.531543   0.531065
7Y                 0.532852   0.533457   0.532856
8Y                 0.534207   0.534802   0.534325
9M                 0.519511   0.519377   0.519024
9Y                 0.535314   0.535847   0.535558
```

I would like the results sorted by the tenor column:

```
tenor            2014-01-01 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
1D                 0.517125   0.517874   0.518552
1M                   0.5175     0.5181     0.5186
2M                 0.518159   0.518451   0.518536
3M                   0.5187     0.5188     0.5186
4M                  0.51912   0.519113   0.518865
5M                  0.51949   0.519418    0.51916
6M                   0.5197     0.5196     0.5193
9M                 0.519511   0.519377   0.519024
1Y                   0.5198     0.5197     0.5193
18M                0.521228   0.521406   0.520882
2Y                 0.523097   0.523405     0.5228
3Y                 0.525054   0.525254   0.524647
4Y                 0.527055   0.527151   0.526752
5Y                 0.529054   0.529256   0.528957
6Y                 0.531099   0.531543   0.531065
7Y                 0.532852   0.533457   0.532856
8Y                 0.534207   0.534802   0.534325
9Y                 0.535314   0.535847   0.535558
```

I've thought about writing a custom sort function that would convert the tenor values to days when comparing and then using that with pandas (not sure how yet).

I've investigated using [google visualization pivot](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Pivot) but that only seems to work on a query not on an existing DataTable.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare day unit with month unit is fuzzy, for example which is large: 30D or 1M? If this is no problem, you can use `reindex()` method to reorder the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df_pivot = df.pivot(index='tenor', columns='date', values='value')

DayCounts = {"D":1, "M":365.0/12, "Y":365}
index = sorted(df_pivot.index, key=lambda v:int(v[:-1])*DayCounts[v[-1]])

df_pivot.reindex(index)
```

output:

```
date  2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03
1D      0.517125    0.517874    0.518552
1M      0.517500    0.518100    0.518600
2M      0.518159    0.518451    0.518536
3M      0.518700    0.518800    0.518600
4M      0.519120    0.519113    0.518865
5M      0.519490    0.519418    0.519160
6M      0.519700    0.519600    0.519300
9M      0.519511    0.519377    0.519024
1Y      0.519800    0.519700    0.519300
18M     0.521228    0.521406    0.520882
2Y      0.523097    0.523405    0.522800
3Y      0.525054    0.525254    0.524647
4Y      0.527055    0.527151    0.526752
5Y      0.529054    0.529256    0.528957
6Y      0.531099    0.531543    0.531065
7Y      0.532852    0.533457    0.532856
8Y      0.534207    0.534802    0.534325
9Y      0.535314    0.535847    0.535558
```